# C++ most lightweight method of deferring a function call

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I am making light-weight co-operative threads for a C++ virtual machine, and while the threads are working just fine, there is a cost to deferring a std::function call:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline Thread* create(const T& func, Args&&... args)
{
...
    auto* thread = new (xxx) Thread(
        [func, args...] () {
            self()->exit( func(args...) );
        });
```

The function above will store a std::function with arguments in another std::function, which allows deferring the call to after the clone syscall has completed and we are running in (among other things) a new stack.

The function is then simply called as if it was the start function of the thread and its storage is freed once it returns or the thread exits.

The API is like normal C++ threads: You pass a function and then the arguments. Is there any way to make the deferred call cheaper? Which options are there? I'm using all the latest compilers (Clang-11, GCC-9.1) with C++17 enabled currently.

The code is available here: https://github.com/fwsGonzo/libriscv/blob/master/binaries/barebones/libc/microthread.hpp#L95

I think that there has to be a full copy of the arguments. When you create a new thread and immediately call it the parameters are still available, because the parent thread is still there waiting. However, it is possible to go back to the main thread and leave the function, which makes the parameters go out of scope, while the new thread is yielded. Not sure how to solve that other than to copy/move the args.

Let's compare microthreads against Lua coroutines.
No arguments:

```
libriscv: micro threads => median 529ns  lowest: 518ns  highest: 586ns
lua5.3: coroutines => median 687ns  lowest: 667ns  highest: 727ns
```

With arguments:

```
libriscv: micro thread args => median 2261ns  lowest: 2181ns  highest: 2725ns
lua5.3: coroutine args => median 762ns  lowest: 735ns  highest: 1051ns
```

Capture by reference:

```
libriscv: micro thread args => median 643ns  lowest: 612ns  highest: 1319ns
lua5.3: coroutine args => median 748ns  lowest: 718ns  highest: 842ns
```

Passing arguments to the microthread causes a heap allocation, and it completely ruins the performance vs. Lua coroutines. Now, allocations on libriscv are not really that slow, but they can't beat just pushing onto the stack.

Comment: What are the lifetimes of parameters?

Comment: I added some more information at the end of my question above. Thanks.

Comment: What is the performance problem with your current one? Is it just that someone has to store the parameters, just like happens with a *regular* function call (except that you didn't write the code to actually do it)?

Comment: Are you looking for something like that: `[func, tup = std::tuple{std::move(args)...}](){ self()->exit(std::apply(func, std::move(ts))); };` to move instead of copy?

Comment: That would certainly be an improvement @Jarod42, but I am also looking to see if it's possible to avoid some memory allocations. The sky is the limit here. Is it possible to store the arguments on the newly created stack of the new thread? If I can store the arguments there then I don't have to create an intermediate lambda.

Comment: @Jarod42 Your idea was very helpful, as it saves 67 instructions for a single std::string, and almost no additional cost for simpler calls (it was around +5 instructions depending on the call.)

Comment: There's a lighter weight [function_ref](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0792r2.html&ved=2ahUKEwjO1sby6NboAhVhdc0KHVNqArkQFjAAegQIBRAC&usg=AOvVaw2wGr-zcK6qkB3_mCm3MaRu) being proposed. The implementation is really simple. Maybe that'll fit your needs.

Comment: I have made some measurements against Lua coroutines and it's really the malloc to put the arguments on heap that makes them way worse. When I measure argument-less threads to argument-less coroutines I win out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended solving this problem by storing the arguments in a tuple on the new threads stack, like so:

```
// store arguments on stack
char* args_addr = stack_bot + sizeof(Thread);
auto* tuple = new (args_addr) std::tuple<Args&&...>{std::move(args)...};

// store the thread at the beginning of the stack
Thread* thread = new (stack_bot) Thread(
[func, tuple] ()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<void, decltype(func(args...))>)
    {
        std::apply(func, std::move(*tuple));
        self()->exit(0);
    } else {
        self()->exit( std::apply(func, std::move(*tuple)) );
    }
});
```

C++ really does have a tool for everything sometimes. Hope this helps a future someone. This massively improved the performance of the microthreads and I ended up winning out against Lua coroutines, both with and without arguments:

```
libriscv: micro threads => median 564ns  lowest: 516ns  highest: 807ns
lua5.3: coroutines => median 737ns  lowest: 696ns  highest: 857ns
libriscv: micro thread args => median 796ns  lowest: 758ns  highest: 874ns
lua5.3: coroutine args => median 803ns  lowest: 770ns  highest: 866ns
```

Cheers.